# Is $\mathbb{S}^1 \wedge E$ a cofinal subspectra in $\Sigma E$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, stable-homotopy-theory

I'm following the proof of Switzer's "Algebraic Topology and Homotopy" of the known result

> **Theorem**. Let $E$ be a (CW-pre)spectra. There is a natural (up to homotopy) homotopy equivalence $E \wedge \mathbb{S}^1 \to \Sigma E$.

Here $\Sigma E$ is the spectra given by shifting one position, $(\Sigma E)_n = E_{n+1}$.

In the proof given the author defines homotopy inverses over $\mathbb{S}^1 \wedge E_n$ for each $n$ such the natural diagrams commute up to homotopy and pretty much establishes that this finishes the proof (using the generalization of Whitehead's theorem for spectra). What I don't understand is that this seems to use the fact that $\mathbb{S}^1 \wedge E$ is cofinal in $\Sigma E$, but, wouldn't this in turn imply the theorem in a trivial manner? I'm sure there is a subtle problem somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Any light that can be shed on this would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\mathbb S^1\wedge E$ is cofinal in $\Sigma E$, then the two must be isomorphic. As long as the author really does use cofinality, the proof is indeed trivial. I would have to see the argument to check that cofinality is used.